# Nodejs - process hangs on exit (Ctrl+C)

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a node.js project which does many things, it spawns child processes, it opens an http and socket.io server, etc..

When I run it from the console, closing it with `Ctrl+C`, it just hangs.
From webstorm, stopping the process is a two-step process, first I hit stop, then I need to hit the button again, only the second time the button is a skull icon.

Now, I understand it leaves something open or hanging, but I just can't figure out what, I tried to track all the places where I start a process and made sure I'm killing them properly.

Is there a way to debug this and find out what's making my process hang? Could it be logging that open a write stream and never closes? I'm not even sure what kind of things will make a process hang on SIGINT.

EDIT: I've downloaded `pstree` to see if any of the child processes that the main process spawns stay alive. It looks like they all terminate properly - the main node process is the only one left.

Comment: Try out [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)

Comment: This is usually because some event listeners haven't been unregistered. That's pretty broad, but for any more information you'll need to post some code.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt - any kind of pointer would be appreciated - what kind of event listeners could cause the process to stay alive after SIGINT?

Comment: Without seeing code, there's no way I can know. Perhaps try closing server objects on the signal, although this should be automatic.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Scripts are themselves responsible for properly shutting down once they listen to the `SIGINT` event, as the default handler (killing the process) is disabled then.

Check out this example program:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('SIGINT');
});
console.log('PID: ', process.pid);

var http = require('http'); // HTTP server to keep the script up long enough
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Execute it and then try killing it: **It won't work**. The `SIGINT` signal will always get passed to your custom build signal handler. In order to properly shut the process down you will have to manually call [`process.exit()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code):

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('SIGINT');
    process.exit();
});
console.log('PID: ', process.pid);

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

`process.exit()` will:

1. [Set some internal flags](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/75adde07f9a2de7f38a67bec72bd377d450bdb52/src/node.js#L592)
2. [Call](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/75adde07f9a2de7f38a67bec72bd377d450bdb52/src/node.js#L593) the [`process.on('exit')`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) handlers
3. Call [`process.reallyExit`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/75adde07f9a2de7f3/src/node.cc#L2696)
4. Which [will call](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/75adde07f9a2de7f38a67bec72bd377d450bdb52/src/node.cc#L1883) the C++ [`exit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) function, therefore `process.exit()` is *final* and will cause a shutdown (unless you block execution by an endless loop in your `on('exit')` handler).

---

Long story short: Your code probably listens to `SIGINT` somewhere. You can fetch a list of those listeners via:

```
var listeners = process.listeners('SIGINT');
```

You can even pretty print them on the console:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
    console.log(listeners[i].toString());
}
```

Using the information I gave above you can easily compile yet another `SIGINT`-handler that will list all the handlers and then cleanly exit the process, hopefully leading your path to the *naughty* ones:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('Nice SIGINT-handler');
    var listeners = process.listeners('SIGINT');
    for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        console.log(listeners[i].toString());
    }

    process.exit();
});
```

---

Complete program for testing:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('Naughty SIGINT-handler');
});
process.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('exit');
});
console.log('PID: ', process.pid);

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('Nice SIGINT-handler');
    var listeners = process.listeners('SIGINT');
    for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        console.log(listeners[i].toString());
    }

    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: huh, amazingly simple. I had a SIGINT catcher that closed services and processes. I must've had `process.exit` in the code before and I guess I just assumed it wasn't needed so I removed that :) Thank you

Comment: This is great. I wish that https://nodejs.org/api/process.html had this information.