# How to hide password in the nodejs console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to hide password input. I see many answers in stackoverflow but I can't verify value if I press backspace. The condition return false.

I tried several solution to overwrite the function but I got an issue with buffer if I press backspace, I got invisible character `\b`.

I press : "A", backspace, "B", I have in my buffer this : "\u0041\u0008\u0042" (toString() = 'A\bB') and not "B".

I have :

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("password : ", function(password) {
    console.log("Your password : " + password);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get password from input using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708787/get-password-from-input-using-node-js)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Overwrite _writeToOutput of application's readline interface  : https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v9.5.0/lib/readline.js#L291

To hide your password input, you can use :

### FIRST SOLUTION : "password : [=-]"

This solution has animation when you press a touch :

```
password : [-=]
password : [=-]
```

The code :

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.stdoutMuted = true;

rl.query = "Password : ";
rl.question(rl.query, function(password) {
  console.log('\nPassword is ' + password);
  rl.close();
});

rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(stringToWrite) {
  if (rl.stdoutMuted)
    rl.output.write("\x1B[2K\x1B[200D"+rl.query+"["+((rl.line.length%2==1)?"=-":"-=")+"]");
  else
    rl.output.write(stringToWrite);
};
```

This sequence "\x1B[2K\x1BD" uses two escapes sequences :

- ***Esc* [2K :** clear entire line.
- ***Esc* D :** move/scroll window up one line.

To learn more, read this : http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

### SECOND SOLUTION : "password : ****"

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.stdoutMuted = true;

rl.question('Password: ', function(password) {
  console.log('\nPassword is ' + password);
  rl.close();
});

rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(stringToWrite) {
  if (rl.stdoutMuted)
    rl.output.write("*");
  else
    rl.output.write(stringToWrite);
};
```

### You can clear history with :

```
rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Subject, the code works just as what I expected. Would you please explain a little bit about what the \033[2K\033D means?

Comment: \033[2K\033D, uses two sequences "Esc[2K" and "EscD". First, clear entire line, second move/scroll window up one line.

Comment: If you are using strict mode change '\033[2K\033[200D' to '\x1B[2K\x1B[200D'. This just changes the deprecated octal escapes into equivalent hexadecimal escapes.

Comment: Thanks. It helps, but I cannot break my script with "ctrl+c" like usual. Why?

Comment: @Kenjiro You need to set "CTRL+C" trigger on "SIGINT" with readline like this : https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_sigint

Comment: @HorsSujet I tried it and added it like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864127/nodejs-process-hangs-on-exit-ctrlc but Still can't.  Do you know why?

Comment: @Kenjiro Do you try : `rl.on("SIGINT", function() { rl.clearLine(); return process.exit(); });` ?

Comment: second solution doesn't work for me. First it shows my password as I type it and then a second time. (I see the second time is intentional). I really can't figure out why either solution would work (but the first does for me) since the question is executed prior to setting up the write settings

Comment: I think the issue in second example is `if (!rl.stdoutMuted)` should not have the `!`

Comment: yeah, if you remove the `!` from the `if (!rl.stdoutMuted)` the second example will work.

Comment: The second solution has a weird behaviour of the return key. It prints `Password: `, then if you enter 'a' and press return the total content of the first output line is `Password: **` without a line break. Any subsequent console logging will log right after that in the same line. I fixed it by testing for the newline character in `rl._writeToOutput` like so: `if (rl.stdoutMuted && stringToWrite != '\r\n' &&  stringToWrite != '\n' && stringToWrite != '\r')`

Comment: @chrwoizi yeah this is also true when erasing the password, as the interface will re-render the whole line with the test. try
```
  if (password) {
    rl._writeToOutput = (s) => {
      const v = s.split(question)
      if (v.length == '2') {
        rl.output.write(question)
        rl.output.write('*'.repeat(v[1].length))
      } else {
        rl.output.write('*')
      }
    }
  }
``` (https://github.com/artdecocode/reloquent/blob/master/src/lib/ask.js#L23) or NPM package reloquent

Comment: Using a private (internal part) of a class/interface (here __writeToOutput for readline) wouldn't be a good idea. The types can only commit to maintain their public interface.

Comment: I hate the `_writeToOutput` solution (because of what @AlexSed  mentioned) but it works perfectly and it's very simple.

Answer (score 62):

This can be handled with readline by intercepting the output through a muted stream, as is done in the read project on npm (https://github.com/isaacs/read/blob/v1.0.7/lib/read.js):

```
var readline = require('readline');
var Writable = require('stream').Writable;

var mutableStdout = new Writable({
  write: function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (!this.muted)
      process.stdout.write(chunk, encoding);
    callback();
  }
});

mutableStdout.muted = false;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: mutableStdout,
  terminal: true
});

rl.question('Password: ', function(password) {
  console.log('\nPassword is ' + password);
  rl.close();
});

mutableStdout.muted = true;
```

Comment: Though this code works fine, I wonder if it's _proper_. You don't pass the callback to `stdout.write` but call it with success unconditionally, and suppress any errors that way. Unfortunately, passing the callback makes it stop working and requires the muting to be done with a timeout of 0 (which then smells like a race condition to me).

Comment: Don't miss **`Enter`** key: *`if (!this.muted || ['\n', '\r\n'].includes(chunk.toString())) ...`*

Comment: Or just use the `read` package directly... https://stackoverflow.com/a/77629369/67824

Comment: The muted false then true is a race condition. It assumes mute false for the prompt to be printed but then mute becomes true before the user can type anything. This won't work with promises. See my answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `readline-sync` module instead of node's `readline`.

Password-hiding functionality is built in via it's "hideEchoBack" option.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync

Comment: `readline-sync` in conjuction with `ttys` allows you to have a password prompt without showing the typed chars. Thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 10):

Another method using `readline`:

```js
var readline = require("readline"),
    rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

rl.input.on("keypress", function (c, k) {
  // get the number of characters entered so far:
  var len = rl.line.length;
  // move cursor back to the beginning of the input:
  readline.moveCursor(rl.output, -len, 0);
  // clear everything to the right of the cursor:
  readline.clearLine(rl.output, 1);
  // replace the original input with asterisks:
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    rl.output.write("*");
  }
});

rl.question("Enter your password: ", function (pw) {
  // pw == the user's input:
  console.log(pw);
  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: Illustrates good solution / simple + effective, and doesn't require installing a module or overwriting a private API. Easy to add a flag to toggle between `keypress` processing depending whether question response should be hidden or not.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me as each character is shown briefly before being replaced

Comment: Suggest `rl.output.write('*'.repeat(len));` instead of `for` loop.

Comment: This still writes the input to stdout - before clearing it and writing `*`, depending on OS/setup may be intercepted/errornous thus MAY LEAK the output, whereas `_writeToOutput` is ugly but intercepts it before writing.

Answer (score 8):

My solution, scraped together from various bits online:

```
import readline from 'readline';

export const hiddenQuestion = query => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  const stdin = process.openStdin();
  process.stdin.on('data', char => {
    char = char + '';
    switch (char) {
      case '\n':
      case '\r':
      case '\u0004':
        stdin.pause();
        break;
      default:
        process.stdout.clearLine();
        readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
        process.stdout.write(query + Array(rl.line.length + 1).join('*'));
        break;
    }
  });
  rl.question(query, value => {
    rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
    resolve(value);
  });
});
```

Usage is like this:

```
// import { hiddenQuestion } from './hidden-question.js';

const main = async () => {
  console.log('Enter your password and I will tell you your password! ');
  const password = await hiddenQuestion('> ');
  console.log('Your password is "' + password + '". ');
};

main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: For a multiple prompt script, to avoid extra new lines being printed for each call to `hiddenQuestion`, you'll want to put a `rl.close()` right before resolving the promise.

Comment: In addition, before the promise resolves you probably want `process.stdin.removeListener("data", onChar);` (this assumes the handler has been extracted into an `onChar` function.

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to add to the marked solution#2.

When we detect the line-ends, I believe we should remove the event handler instead of just `stdin.pause()`. This can be an issue if you are waiting on rl.question/rl.prompt elsewhere. 
In those cases, if `stdin.pause()` was used, it would just exit the program without giving any errors and can be quite annoying to debug.

```
function hidden(query, callback) {
    var stdin = process.openStdin();
    var onDataHandler = function(char) {
        char = char + "";
        switch (char) {
          case "\n": case "\r": case "\u0004":
            // Remove this handler
            stdin.removeListener("data",onDataHandler); 
            break;//stdin.pause(); break;
          default:
            process.stdout.write("\033[2K\033[200D" + query + Array(rl.line.length+1).join("*"));
          break;
        }
    }
    process.stdin.on("data", onDataHandler);

    rl.question(query, function(value) {
      rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
      callback(value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also one can use [tty.ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/tty.html#tty_readstream_setrawmode_mode)
changing mode of `process.stdin`
to disable echoing input characters.

```
let read_Line_Str = "";
let credentials_Obj = {};
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.setRawMode( true );
process.stdout.write( "Enter password:" ); 
process.stdin.on( 'readable', () => {
  const chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if ( chunk !== null ) {
    read_Line_Str += chunk;
    if( 
      chunk == "\n" ||
      chunk == "\r" ||
      chunk == "\u0004"
    ){
      process.stdout.write( "\n" );
      process.stdin.setRawMode( false );
      process.stdin.emit('end'); /// <- this invokes on.end
    }else{
      // providing visual feedback
      process.stdout.write( "*" );  
    }  
  }else{
    //console.log( "readable data chunk is null|empty" );
  }
} );
process.stdin.on( 'end', () => {
  credentials_Obj.user = process.env.USER;
  credentials_Obj.host = 'localhost';
  credentials_Obj.database = process.env.USER;
  credentials_Obj.password = read_Line_Str.trim();
  credentials_Obj.port = 5432;
  //
  connect_To_DB( credentials_Obj );
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

A promisified typescript native version:

This will also handle multiple `question` calls (as @jeffrey-woo pointed out). I chose not to replace input with `*`, as it didn't feel very unix-y, and I found it to be glitchy sometimes if typing too fast anway.

```
import readline from 'readline';

export const question = (question: string, options: { hidden?: boolean } = {}) =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const input = process.stdin;
    const output = process.stdout;

    type Rl = readline.Interface & { history: string[] };
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output }) as Rl;

    if (options.hidden) {
      const onDataHandler = (charBuff: Buffer) => {
        const char = charBuff + '';
        switch (char) {
          case '\n':
          case '\r':
          case '\u0004':
            input.removeListener('data', onDataHandler);
            break;
          default:
            output.clearLine(0);
            readline.cursorTo(output, 0);
            output.write(question);
            break;
        }
      };
      input.on('data', onDataHandler);
    }

    rl.question(question, (answer) => {
      if (options.hidden) rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
      rl.close();
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
```

Usage:

```
(async () => {
  const hiddenValue = await question('This will be hidden', { hidden: true });
  const visibleValue = await question('This will be visible');
  console.log('hidden value', hiddenValue);
  console.log('visible value', visibleValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [prompt](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt) module, as suggested [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/).

```
const prompt = require('prompt');

const properties = [
    {
        name: 'username', 
        validator: /^[a-zA-Z\s\-]+$/,
        warning: 'Username must be only letters, spaces, or dashes'
    },
    {
        name: 'password',
        hidden: true
    }
];

prompt.start();

prompt.get(properties, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { return onErr(err); }
    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  Username: ' + result.username);
    console.log('  Password: ' + result.password);
});

function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I was not able to make this work correctly in an `async` main function, is this implementation only viable in sequential execution?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer suggests we imitate the `read` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/read), but why not just use it? It has almost 5M weekly downloads, regularly updated, and among the contributors you have the guy behind `npm` itself...

```
import { read } from 'read';

const password = await read({
  prompt: "password: ",
  silent: true,
  replace: "*"
};

console.log("Your password: " + password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution which doesn't require any external libraries (besides readline) or a lot of code.

```
// turns off echo, but also doesn't process backspaces
// also captures ctrl+c, ctrl+d
process.stdin.setRawMode(true); 

const rl = require('readline').createInterface({input: process.stdin});
rl.on('close', function() { process.exit(0); }); // on ctrl+c, doesn't work? :(
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (/\u0003\.test(line)/) process.exit(0); // on ctrl+c, but after return :(
    // process backspaces
    while (/\u007f/.test(line)) {
        line = line.replace(/[^\u007f]\u007f/, '').replace(/^\u007f+/, '');
    }

    // do whatever with line
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own take on this, cherry picking from the other answers here. When the user types, there is no output. This is to prevent any data leaks.

```
const readline = require("readline");
    
const hiddenQuestion = (query) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log(query);
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,
        });
        rl._writeToOutput = () => {};
        const stdin = process.openStdin();
        process.stdin.on("data", (char) => {
            char = char.toString("utf-8");
            switch (char) {
                case "\n":
                case "\r":
                case "\u0004":
                    // Finished writing their response
                    stdin.pause();
                    break;
                // You might make this case optional, (Ctrl-C)
                case "\u0003":
                    // Ctrl-C
                    process.exit(0);
                default:
                    process.stdout.clearLine();
                    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
                    break;
            }
        });
        rl.question("", (value) => {
            rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
            rl.close();
            resolve(value);
        });
    });

// Usage example:
void (async () => {
    const password = await hiddenQuestion("What is your password?");
    // do what you want with the password...
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix like style. No symbols on put/paste at all.

```
rl.input.on('keypress', (c) => {
  if (c.charCodeAt() === 127) {
    const len = rl.line.length
    readline.moveCursor(rl.output, -len, 0)
    readline.clearLine(rl.output, 1)
    return
  }
  readline.moveCursor(rl.output, -1, 0)
  readline.clearLine(rl.output, 1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the `_writeToOutput` override, but the solutions here don't seem to handle the arrow-up/history case; I've added that, and TypeScripted it.  Makes use of the fact that readline sends the full query string when you navigate history, and only a single character normally.

Checking the input or using a proper library are better choices, but not always worth the effort. This ios quick-and-dirty, probably still breaks in cases, but I haven't found them (TM):

```
let echo = '*';  // or '' if you prefer
let first: string|undefined;

(this.readline as any)._writeToOutput = (c: string) => {
  if (first==undefined || c.length!=1) {
    if (first==undefined) first = c;
    if (c.startsWith(first)) {
      // rewriting prompt
      (this.readline as any).output?.write(first);
      c = c.slice(first.length);
    } else if (!c.trim()) {
      // user pressed enter, show the enter
      (this.readline as any).output?.write(c);
      c = '';
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    // all other input, and bits after the prompt, use echo char
    (this.readline as any).output?.write(echo);
  }
};
```

And after completion, don't forget this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24037546:

```
(this.readline as any).history = (this.readline as any).history?.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the easiest solution:

```js
import { createInterface } from 'node:readline/promises';

const rl = createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: null,
    terminal: true,
});

const password = await rl.question();
rl.close();
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971780/1015595) is close to the same but more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my comprehensive solution that will run in node without anything from npm. It uses promises and has an option for disabling the echo back when typing. This works in node 20.11.1 and doesn't use the deprecated/removed things other answers have and has no race condition. When it is silent no replacement symbols are shown but it does support backspace and pasting.

```
'use strict';
const readline = require('readline');
const stream = require('stream');

const prompt = (query, promptOptions = {}) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const mutableStdout = new stream.Writable({
      write: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
        //don't print anything typed when silent
        if (!promptOptions.silent) {
          process.stdout.write(chunk, encoding);
        }
        callback();
      },
    });
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: mutableStdout,
      terminal: promptOptions.silent,
    });

    //have to print here so that query is shown even when stdin is silent
    process.stdout.write(query);
    rl.question('', (answer) => {
      if (promptOptions.silent) {
        rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
        //enter will submit without printing. this puts the output on the next line
        process.stdout.write('\n');
      }
      rl.close();
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });

async function main() {
  const user = await prompt('User Name: ');
  const pass = await prompt('Password: ', { silent: true });
  console.log(`${user}:${pass}`);
}

const shell = {
  GENERIC_FAILURE_CODE: 1,
  SUCCESS_CODE: 0,
};
main()
  .then(() => {
    process.exit(shell.SUCCESS_CODE);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('main failed', error);
    process.exit(shell.GENERIC_FAILURE_CODE);
  });
```