# Javascript: Is there any way to clear history of user input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, readline, input-history

I'm creating a Simon Says game where the pattern gets progressively longer as the user gets the pattern correct, but the input history shows their previous pattern inputs. How do I clear this history?

This code is on the CodeHS site. I've researched and tried console.clear();, clear(); and console.API.clear();, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is the section of my code that gets the user's input.

```
//green red blue yellow
var generatedPattern = "grby"

function getUserInput(){
    /*User input of the last round gets saved which shows them 'grb', allowing 
    the user to look back at their previous guess to easily guess the 
    next pattern*/
    guess = readLine("Input guess here: (example: ybbg)");
    if(guess == generatedPattern){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I expect the log to be cleared with clear(); or console.clear();, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: `.clear()` normally clears the console, not the history of input. Which usually isn't even managed by your program, but by the terminal itself.

Comment: Why are you using the console instead of `<input>` fields in the DOM?

Comment: @Barmar Probably because it's a cli application (node.js), not running in the browser? (Would've been better of course to make this clear up-front)

Comment: Yeah, someone needs to tell the people putting `autocomplete=off` in answers.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, it's a cli application. Forgot to note that.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/24037545/1048572 for a similar issue

Comment: [`readLine.createInterface`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options) has a `historySize` option

Comment: You should check Bergi's option, I believe it will lead you to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a custom function that outputs the ANSI escape character :

```
const clearTerminal = () => process.stdout.write('\033c')
```

(Please note that there should be a better way to handle your program, this helper function will just wipe clean your entire window, which is not what you might want)