# How to perform an action on shutdown?

Tags: node.js, application-shutdown

Suppose I write a module handler.js as Express.js middleware:

```
var info = {};

infohandler.setinfo = function(i){ info[i] = Math.random(); }
infohandler.saveinfo = function(){ fs.writeFileSync("info.json", info); }

function handler(req, res, next){ // here are some operation call to infohandler according to req. }

module.exports = handler;
```

And in app.js I import this handler.js:

```
var handler = require("handler");
```

I want to save some information to a file right before server shutdown. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`process.on`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener) to bind to the [`exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) event. This event is called on a graceful shutdown:

```
process.on('exit', function () {
    // your clean up code
});
```

If you want to catch specific signals (such as SIGTERM which is send by default using kill(1)) bind to the name of the signal:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () { /* ... */ });
```

Note that this will [disable the default action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21864127/782822) (shutdown). Make sure to manually call [`process.exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) in there.

Comment: Thanks, but I still not get it, how can I trigger infohandler.saveinfo function?

Comment: @Kuan Call it where it says "your clean up code". Make sure to only perform synchronous operations in there.